# Android phone wi-fi not connecting with perticular network only

Tags: wi-fi, htc

Please refer me to right portal if this is not a right one.

I am having android phone HTC one +. Now problem is that when i am in office and trying to connect with Wi-Fi then it not connect but when i try to connect with any other Wi-Fi network then it easily connect.

I also had visit the service center and Wi-Fi connected easily in their network.

What i can do to solve this issue.

Comment: Yes, Actually My Mobile was blocked in the office network due to some security issues. I consulted with the Network team and they release access for my phone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with another device(HTC touch diamond2). You need to edit network settings. Write by yourself IP-adress, subnet Mask, Router of current Wi-Fi.
I think to find out this information for you will not be difficult.

Comment: Please provide me more info to solve this.As i also concerned with the network administrator they are saying they didn't applied any security on this network.

Comment: The reason isn't in network security. Open wi-fi settings(where you are searching networks) - > find current network and press on it for a long time - > Edit Network - > Show advanced options -> IP settings choose from DHCP to Custom - > Write IP-adress, Gateway, Network prefix length(Your network administrator must give you this info) -> SAVE.
Everything must work ;)

Comment: Thanks David for this i will try this and let you know ..